# What is this plant with narrow stems and purple flowers found in Germany?

Tags: identification, flowers

I found this plant in the pre-Alps in Bavaria/Germany:

[image]

It was located between 900 and 1200m above sea level on a forest meadow in the beginning of July. It was a hot day (>25°C) but not sunny at that time on the meadow. Despite some efforts I can't seem to identify it. My best guess is that is is some sort of Centaurium, maybe Centaurium erythraea? Can you help?

Comment: If no one recognises this plant,please post another picture which shows the foliage and stems, preferably the whole plant.

Comment: And also, open flowers would be very helpful for a positive ID.

Answer (score 2):

Might be [Thlaspi rotundifolium](http://luirig.altervista.org/flora/taxa/index1.php?scientific-name=thlaspi%20rotundifolium). True, the purple in the tight cluster is rather bright in the photo, but sometimes on opening the petal colour can appear to fade a little. The month of flowering is spot on, but the altitude is a bit low for this suggestion.